# Passing string (containing newline) to jar in PHP

Tags: php, shell, sms

I am using an external java library to send SMS. The code that I used to sent is as such:

```
$command = "java -jar vigsyssmscom4.jar \"1\" \"$phoneNum\" \"$message\"";
$apiOutput = shell_exec($command . "\n");
```

However, this code does not allow the $message to contain any newline characters as it will execute the command immediately. Is there anyway that I can pass a string with newline character through the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the jar file and the relevant class to replace all selected character to new line in the message variable. This helps to avoid passing new line characters in the message argument.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at escapeshellarg: http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

```
$message = "hello\nworld";
$command = "echo ".escapeshellarg($message);
$apiOutput = shell_exec($command);
var_dump($apiOutput);
```

Comment: escapeshellarg will remove the newline characters in windows

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Sorry :$. I don't use windows.